# Query syntax error: INSERT ... SELECT ... NOT IN ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, select, syntax-error, sql-insert, unique-key

I have two test databases, `db0` and `bd1`, respectively containing the tables `t0` and `t1`. Each table contains the columns `c0` and `c1` where `c0` has an `unique` index.

Graphically, both tables are defined as:

```
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| c0      | varchar(1) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| c1      | varchar(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to copy rows from `db0.t0` to `db1.t1`. The following query is instructed to:

- copy rows from `t0` to `t1`;
- set column `c1` to `123` in the copied row;
- avoid copying rows if they already exist (all columns equal) in `c1`;
- copy those rows which have equal key (`c0`) but differ otherwise.

The query is:

```
use db1;

insert into t1 (c0, c1)
select c0, 123 from db0.t0
where (db0.t0.c0, db0.t0.c1) not in
    (select c0, c1 from db1.t1)
on duplicate key update;
```

This query gives an SQL syntax error. However, removing its last line makes MySQL accept the syntax and execute the query, but it will eventually throw an error if/when it encounters a row with the same key (`c0`) but different otherwise (`c1`):

```
use db1;

insert into t1 (c0, c1)
select c0, 123 from db0.t0
where (db0.t0.c0, db0.t0.c1) not in
    (select c0, c1 from db1.t1);
```

Looking at MySQL's documentation for the [INSERT ... SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html), I don't seem to be doing anything wrong.

What's going on?

Comment: You simply need to specify which fields you want to update and with what value

Comment: @Capsule That is correct, and solves my question!